# Why does df.isnull().sum() work the way it does?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, axis

When I do df.isnull().sum(), I get the count of null values in a column. But the default axis for .sum() is None, or 0 - which should be summing across the columns.

Why does .sum() calculate the sum down the columns, instead of the rows, when the default says to sum across axis = 0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing the opposite behavior as you explained:

```
Sums across the columns
In [3309]:  df1.isnull().sum(1)                                                                                                                                                                
Out[3309]: 
0     0
1     1
2     0
3     0
4     0
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    0
dtype: int64
```

Sums down the columns

```
In [3310]:  df1.isnull().sum()                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[3310]: 
date        0
variable    1
value       0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Uh.. this is not what I am seeing for functionality.  Let's look at this small example.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[np.nan, np.nan, 3],'B':[1,1,3]}, index =[*'abc'])
print(df)
print(df.isnull().sum())
print(df.sum())
```

Note the columns are uppercase 'A' and 'B', and the index or row indexes are lowercase.

Output:

```
     A  B
a  NaN  1
b  NaN  1
c  3.0  3

A    2
B    0
dtype: int64

A    3.0
B    5.0
dtype: float64
```

Per [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html#pandas-dataframe-sum):

> axis : {index (0), columns (1)} Axis for the function to be applied
>   on.

Comment: This is actually exactly the same kind of output I'm seeing - what's confusing to me is that df.isnull().sum() has default axis = None, which is the same as axis = 0. Which should be summing across the rows - so the output we would see is a: 1, b: 1, c: 0.
Instead, the output we see is A: 2, B:0, which indicates it's summing down the columns (since the columns are A, B and the rows are a, b, c). Does that make sense?

Comment: Axis = 0 zero means summing along the index axis, which is a sum of the column values.  Yeah.... I get your meaning somewhat confusing what "0 index" means.  When I first learned pandas a few years ago, I struggled with the same.   I simply over time got used to pandas doing "most" things along the index axis by default, which means operations happen on a single column at a time.

Comment: @ChristineJiang Would you consider upvoting and accepting an answer to your SO questions? https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 1):

The axis parameter is orthogonal to the direction which you wish to sum.

Unfortunately, the pandas documentation for sum doesn't currently make this clear, but the documentation for count does:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html

Parameters
axis{0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0
If 0 or ‘index’ counts are generated for each column. If 1 or ‘columns’ counts are generated for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Hey let me tell you what I think it does..
first `.isnull()` does is it returns value 1 if any column value is null and then `.sum()` will add that 1 that `.isnull()` returned and keep on adding as many 1 `.isnull()` will return means as many null values are present and if there are no null values `.isnull()` will simply return 0 and adding 0 will not result any thing but 0.
I think it helps you understand